# How to remove/replace specific parentheses from a string containing multiple parentheses in R

Tags: r, regex

Given the following string of parentheses, I am trying to remove one specific parentheses,
where the position of one of its bracket is marked with 1.

```
((((((((((((((((((********))))))))))))))))))
00000000000000000000000000000000010000000000
```

So for the above example, the solution I am looking for is

```
((((((((((-(((((((********)))))))-))))))))))
00000000000000000000000000000000010000000000
```

I am tried using `strsplit` function from `stringr` to split and get the indexes of the bracket marked with 1. But I am not sure how I can get the index of its corresponding closing bracket.
Could anyone give some input on this..

What I did..

```
a = "((((((((((-(((((((********)))))))-))))))))))"
b = "00000000000000000000000000000000010000000000"
which(unlist(strsplit(b,"")) == 1)
#[1] 34
a_mod = unlist(strsplit(a,""))[-34]
```

here, I removed one bracket of the parentheses which I wanted to remove but I do not know how I can remove its corresponding opening bracket which is in 11th position in this example

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Comment: @G.Grothendieck 0/1 is also a string/vector of same length as the object containing the string with parentheses. Hence it also shows the position of paren which is to be removed

Comment: OK. Also did you just want to replace those parentheses with minus signs or did you want to remove them and the minus signs are just showing which ones you want to remove?

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I would like to replace them with minus signs. Thank you for the answer below. I will try to digest it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locate the 1 in b giving pos2 and also calculate the length of b giving n.  Then replace positions pos2 and pos1 = n-pos2+1 with minus characters.  See ?gregexpr and ?nchar and ?substr for more info. No packages are used.

```
pos2 <- regexpr(1, b)
n <- nchar(a)
pos1 <- n - pos2 + 1
substr(a, pos1, pos1) <- substr(a, pos2, pos2) <- "-"

a
## [1] "((((((((((-(((((((********)))))))-))))))))))"
```

Comment: Thank you it works. But I am wondering how I can optimize it, when a is not symmetric and has nested paren.. for example  `a = "((((****))))((((((((((((((((((********))))))))))))))))))"` and `b =  "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000"`

Comment: I have changed the variable names in the answer to use pos1 and pos2 as the positions of the two minus signs so replace the pos1<-... line with pos1 <- n - pos2 + 1 + regexpr(")(", a, fixed = TRUE) to handle the fact that the second chunk does not start at position 1.

Answer (score 0):

Since the parentheses are paired the index of the close parentheses is just the length of the string minus the index of the open parentheses (they're equidistant from the string ends)

```
library(stringr)
string <- "((((((((((((((((((********))))))))))))))))))"
b <- "00000000000000000000000000000000010000000000"
location <- str_locate(b, "1")[1]
len <- str_length(string)

substr(string, location, location) <- "-"
substr(string, len-location, len-location) <- "-"
string
"(((((((((-((((((((********)))))))-))))))))))"
```

Comment: Thank you.. but it will work for only this given example.. I am looking to implement this for any similar problem

Comment: @GPVS I've edited the solution to use your index string

Answer (score 0):

You should show what you have tried. One very simple way that would work for your example would be to do something like:

```r
gsub("\\*){8}", "\\*)))))))-", "((((((((((((((((((********))))))))))))))))))")
#> [1] "((((((((((((((((((********)))))))-))))))))))"
```

**Edit:**
In response to your question: It depends what you mean by other similar examples.
If you go purely by position in the string, you already have an excellent answer from G. Grothendieck. If you want a solution where you want to replace the nth closing bracket, for example, you could do:

```r
s <- "((((((((((((((((((********))))))))))))))))))"
replace_par <- function(n, string) {
    sub(paste0("(!?\\))(\\)){", n, "}"), 
     paste0(paste(rep(")", (n-1)), collapse=""), "-"), 
     string, perl = TRUE)}
replace_par(8, s)
#> [1] "((((((((((((((((((********)))))))-)))))))))"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function that does the replacement the way you want:

```
strreplace <- function(x,y,val = "-")
{
  regmatches(x,regexpr(1,y)) <- val
  sub(".([(](?:[^()]|(?1))*+[)])(?=-)", paste0(val, "\\1"), x, perl = TRUE)
}

a <- "((((((((((((((((((********))))))))))))))))))"
b < -"00000000000000000000000000000000010000000000"
strreplace(a, b)
[1] "((((((((((-(((((((********)))))))-))))))))))"

# Nested paranthesis
a = "((((****))))((((((((((((((((((********))))))))))))))))))"
b = "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000"
strreplace(a,b)
[1] "((((****))))((((((((((-(((((((********)))))))-))))))))))"
```